# Apache 2.2 default virtual host for IP address

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

OS: CentOS 6.9. HTTPD version 2.2

I have two IP addresses and a dozen of virtual hosts on one of them. What I need is to be able to switch what vhost is displayed by default when a visitor opens just the IP address in browser.

Currently the only way I know I can achieve that is by replacing the virtuals and the first one works as default. I am looking for a better solution. Is there one? I need some kind of directive, so  I can switch the default virtual host with a script instead of manually editing httpd.conf.

I spent whole morning googling. Found the following info:

Set `ServerAlias my.2nd.ip.addr` - did not work for me.

Set `VirtualHost _default_:80` instead of VirtualHost `my.2nd.ip.addr:80` - not the desired effect.

Set `ServerName my.2nd.ip.addr` and add the domain as `ServerAlias` - still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you hinted, "the first vhost" will be opened by default when visiting by IP address.

The tricky part is understanding how Apache decides which one is the "first"; actually it sorts the active/enabled vhosts per *filename*, and the lower/first filename in an ascending sort, that corresponds to a vhost using that IP address wins, and is selected as the "first".

So no matter the vhost name, if you name a file as `0.conf` or `0actualvhostname.conf` for the first IP address, and for instance, `1.conf` for the second IP address, those vhost files will "win" and be used as the default vhosts to be opened when your server is browsed by IP address.

This is also the reason why in Debian, for instance, the default Apache vhost configuration file is named `000-default.conf`.

You also need to restart Apache after the vhost file name change; as in:

```
sudo apache2ctl -k graceful
```